# R says my function isn't a function when I use sapply on it

Tags: r, finance

I'm trying to use the sapply function to make a vector with option prices. I've got a function that returns the option prices but when I try to use the sapply function on it, I recieve the error message:

> Error in match.fun(FUN) :
>   'binomial_option(n, type)' is not a function, character or symbol.

I don't really get why it would say it's not a function but because in the envíronment it is designated as a function. Here is my code:

```r
#EXAMPLE PARAMETERS
strike=100
startprice = 110
sigma = 0.15
r=0.1
R=r+1
alpha = r-0.5*sigma^2
T = 1

#AktivTræ
StockTree <- function(n){
  tree = matrix(0, nrow = n+1, ncol =  n+1)
  dt = T/n
  u = exp(sigma*sqrt(dt))
  d = exp(-sigma*sqrt(dt))
  for(i in 1:(n+1)){
    for(j in 1:i){
      tree[i,j] <- startprice*u^(j-1)*d^((i-1)-(j-1))
    }
  }
  return(tree)
}

StockTree(5)

#q-ssh.
q_prob <- function(n){
  dt = T/n
  u = exp(sigma*sqrt(dt))
  d = exp(-sigma*sqrt(dt))

  return((exp(r*dt)-d)/(u-d))
}

q_prob(4)

#OptionsTræ
OptionValue <- function(n,type,tree){
  dt = T/n
  q = q_prob(n)
  OptionTree = matrix(0,nrow=nrow(tree), ncol=ncol(tree))

  if(type == 'put'){
    OptionTree[nrow(OptionTree),] <- pmax(strike-tree[nrow(tree),],0)
  }else if(type == 'call'){
    OptionTree[nrow(OptionTree),] <- pmax(tree[nrow(tree),]-strike,0)
  }
  for (i in (nrow(tree)-1):1) {
    for (j in 1:i){
      OptionTree[i,j] = ((1-q)*OptionTree[i+1,j]+q*OptionTree[i+1,j+1])/exp(r*dt)
    }
  }
  return(OptionTree)
}

OptionValue(5,'call',StockTree((5)))

#Standard Binomial Model
binomial_option <- function(n,type){
  q <- q_prob(n)
  tree <- StockTree(n)
  option <- OptionValue(n,type,tree)
  return(option[1,1])
}

binomial_option(500,'call')

6#New and improved?

Yeet <- function(n,type){
  g <- (1:n)
  Vec = sapply(g,binomial_option(n,type))
  return(Vec)
}

Yeet(5,"Call")
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify which argument of binomial_option you want the sequential values of g to be in your sapply.

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
Yeet <- function(n,type){
  g <- (1:n)
  Vec = sapply(g,function(x) binomial_option(x,type))
  return(Vec)
}

Yeet(5,"call")
```

Output:

```
[1] 20.42243 20.32801 19.99258 20.30529 20.16248
```

(I assume that you wanted the values of `g` to become the `n` argument of binomial_option)

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
Yeet <- function(n, type){
  g <- 1:n
  Vec = sapply(g, function(x) binomial_option(x, type))
  return(Vec)
}

Yeet(5,"call")
#[1] 20.42243 20.32801 19.99258 20.30529 20.16248
```